# How to Automatically OpenURL on NSTimer in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I'm using the following code to open a URL with a `UIButton` in Swift

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
```

This works very well on its own, but I'm looking for away to do this with an `NSTimer` with the goal being that the `URL` opens without any **"buttons pressed"** by the user.

Can anyone provide assistance?

Comment: It's no different than running any other code when a timer fires.

Comment: BTW - since it is unlikely you need a repeating timer for this, use `dispatch_after` instead of a timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift use:

```
dispatch_after(2.0, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    // call your button action here
})
```

You don't really need a timer in your case unless you're repeating the opening of this URL.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Try like this in swift language

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.0, target: self, selector: "timerFunctionRun", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

and function Like ths

```
func timerFunctionRun () {
  UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
}
```

its work fine ...